# how can I add multiple options of an array into a <p> using dataset?

Tags: javascript, html, css

im building a quiz and i have multiple questions and they all have multiple choices.
i dont know exaclty the right terms, so forgive me for that.

for my quiz, i have this question:

> ```
>  let questions = [
>  {
>   question: "Questions 1"
>     choice1: "answer 1",
>     choice2: "answer 2",
>     choice3: "answer 3",
>     choice4: "answer 4",
>   answer: "answer 1",
>  },
> ```

and i was using this logic:

> ```
>      choices.forEach(function (choice)  {
>       const number = choice.dataset['number']
>       choice.innerText = currentQuestion['choice' + number]
>      })
> ```

the question and answer go tho this div:

> ```
>   <div class="choice-container">
>     <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
>     <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">Choice</p>
>   </div>
> ```

before that, i had a simpler JS, and i want to use it

```html
let questionsQuiz = [   
  {
    question: "question",
    answers: [
      "1,
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
    ],
    correctAnswer: "4",   
    },
 ]
```

i want to use the second array, i could make it work first but i was creating elemet buttons.

how can a "connect" each answer to the ?

Comment: If ever you add both question and answer to the clientside you can expect an unusually high number of passes. It is trivial to look in the code and fund the correct answer. If you have PHP or similar server side language available send each answer to the server to be judged right/wrong

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample code for you.

This code takes the questions from the object and renders them in the wrap element. Each element containing an answer is assigned a click listener. The question and answer have a `data` attribute. When a response is clicked, the `checkAnswer()` function checks the `data` attributes of the question and the clicked response and compares it with those specified in the object.

I hope I have been helpful.

```js
let questions = [
    {
        question: "Questions 1",
        choice: ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4"],
        answer: 1,
    },
    {
        question: "Questions 2",
        choice: ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4"],
        answer: 3,
    },
    {
        question: "Questions 3",
        choice: ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4"],
        answer: 2,
    },
];

var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');

questions.forEach((el, i) => {

    var vrp = document.createElement('div');
    vrp.setAttribute('data-id', i);

    var q = document.createElement('p');
    q.innerText = el.question;
    vrp.appendChild(q);

    el.choice.forEach((e, i) => {
        var a = document.createElement('p');
        a.innerText = e;
        a.setAttribute('data-ans', i);
        vrp.appendChild(a);

        a.addEventListener('click', checkAnswer);
    });

    wrap.appendChild(vrp);

});

function checkAnswer() {
    var q = this.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id');
    var a = this.getAttribute('data-ans');

    if (questions[+q].answer - 1 === +a) {
        console.log('Correct answer!');
    } else {
        console.log('Not a correct answer!');
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='wrap'></div>
```